# Using roxygen2 and doxygen on the same package?

Tags: c, r, documentation, doxygen, roxygen2

I have an `R` package that uses `roxygen2`. It has some `C` code in `/src`, and I have just started working with `Doxygen`. Are there any ways to combine the documentation or integrate compiling with roxygen2? Any "best practices" for where to put the `C` code documentation?

Googling for roxygen2 and doxygen primarily leads to **roxygen is similar to doxygen** results. I have found a few packages with Doxyfiles, but no consistent organization. For example, `lme4` has [`inst/doc/Doxyfile`](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/) output to a folder called `doxygen` outside the `lme4` source directory. There is also a Doxyfile in the root directory of the Matrix (but in previous releases was in `inst`. This documentation is also exported outside the package directory.

Is there any reason not to include the `C` documentation inside a package, or why is Doxygen so infrequently used within R packages, despite widespread use of `C`?

**update:** see related [roxygen2 feature request](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/326)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if you use Rcpp you can use roxygen2 to document your exported C++ functions

Comment: I guess Doxygen is not used in R packages, because people do not document their C code. C code is almost never part of the API and R package provides, so people just do not document it. If you want to put your C docs in the package, just generate the HTML from a Makefile and put it in inst/.

Comment: I don't know roxygen, but maybe it has some xml output, as doxygen has, and you can combine it with some xslt and create a complete doc from that.

Comment: Are you trying to include roxygen2 input in doxyten output or the other way around?

Answer (score 4):

I personally use the following code in a "dataManagement" package I call in all my scripts. It has roxygen documentation and examples. You actually simply call
     document()
and have doxygen ran on the C code, in
     src/
. The doc is put in 
     inst/doxygen
So that your package is CRAN ready.

The R documentation being designed for R *end users* not supposed to look at the C code I didn't integrate the C code documentation in the classic R documentation but it would probably be a good practice to copy the resulting C documentation as a "vignette".

```
    library("testthat")
    library("devtools")

    #' @title Replace a value for a given tag on file in memory
    #' @description Scan the lines and change the value for the named tag if one line has this tag, 
    #'    add a line at the end if no line has this tag and return a warning if several lines
    #'    matching the tag
    #' @param fileStrings A vector with each string containing a line of the file
    #' @param tag The tag to be searched for 
    #' @param newVal The new value for the tag
    #' @return The vector of strings with the new value
    #' @examples
    #' fakeFileStrings <- c("Hello = world","SURE\t= indeed","Hello = you")
    #' 
    #' expect_warning(ReplaceTag(fakeFileStrings,"Hello","me"))
    #' 
    #' newFake <- ReplaceTag(fakeFileStrings,"SURE","me")
    #' expect_equal(length(newFake), length(fakeFileStrings))
    #' expect_equal(length(grep("SURE",newFake)), 1)
    #' expect_equal(length(grep("me",newFake)), 1)
    #' 
    #' newFake <- ReplaceTag(fakeFileStrings,"Bouh","frightened?")
    #' expect_equal(length(newFake), length(fakeFileStrings)+1)
    #' expect_equal(length(grep("Bouh",newFake)), 1)
    #' expect_equal(length(grep("frightened?",newFake)), 1)
    ReplaceTag <- function(fileStrings,tag,newVal){
        iLine <- grep(paste0("^",tag,"\\>"),fileStrings)
        nLines <- length(iLine)
        if(nLines == 0){
            line <- paste0(tag,"\t= ",newVal)
            iLine <- length(fileStrings)+1
        }else if (nLines > 0){
            line <- gsub("=.*",paste0("= ",newVal),fileStrings[iLine])
            if(nLines >1){
                warning(paste0("File has",nLines,"for key",tag,"check it up manually"))
            }
        }
        fileStrings[iLine] <- line
        return(fileStrings)
    }
    #' Prepares the R package structure for use with doxygen
    #' @description Makes a configuration file in inst/doxygen
    #'     and set a few options: 
    #'     \itemize{
    #'        \item{EXTRACT_ALL = YES}
    #'        \item{INPUT = src/}
    #'        \item{OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = inst/doxygen/}
    #'     }
    #' @param rootFolder The root of the R package
    #' @return NULL
    #' @examples 
    #' \dontrun{
    #' DoxInit()
    #' }
    #' @export
    DoxInit <- function(rootFolder="."){
        doxyFileName <- "Doxyfile"
        initFolder <- getwd()
        if(rootFolder != "."){
            setwd(rootFolder)
        }
        rootFileYes <- length(grep("DESCRIPTION",dir()))>0
        # prepare the doxygen folder
        doxDir <- "inst/doxygen"
        if(!file.exists(doxDir)){
            dir.create(doxDir,recursive=TRUE)
        }
        setwd(doxDir)

        # prepare the doxygen configuration file
        system(paste0("doxygen -g ",doxyFileName))
        doxyfile <- readLines("Doxyfile")
        doxyfile <- ReplaceTag(doxyfile,"EXTRACT_ALL","YES")
        doxyfile <- ReplaceTag(doxyfile,"INPUT","src/")
        doxyfile <- ReplaceTag(doxyfile,"OUTPUT_DIRECTORY","inst/doxygen/")
        cat(doxyfile,file=doxyFileName,sep="\n")
        setwd(initFolder)
        return(NULL)
    }

    #' devtools document function when using doxygen
    #' @description Overwrites devtools::document() to include the treatment of 
    #'    doxygen documentation in src/
    #' @param doxygen A boolean: should doxygen be ran on documents in src?
    #'     the default is TRUE if a src folder exist and FALSE if not
    #' @return The value returned by devtools::document()
    #' @example
    #' \dontrun{
    #' document()
    #' }
    #' @export
    document <- function(doxygen=file.exists("src")){
        if(doxygen){
            doxyFileName<-"inst/doxygen/Doxyfile"
            if(!file.exists(doxyFileName)){
                DoxInit()
            }
            system(paste("doxygen",doxyFileName))
        }
        devtools::document()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I didn't realize that the simple solution was to re-define `devtools::document` to add a system call to `doxygen path/to/Doxyfile`. I've added this to my package. I've also added a [feature request in the roxygen2 github repository](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/326) @hadley

Comment: So - as far as I understand it, the pull request for this feature was not [accepted](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/pull/398). Because I nevertheless wanted to have a convenient way to create doxygen documentation, I created a small [R package](https://github.com/nevrome/rdoxygen) based on the code above.